# Magento Simple Bundle with Fix Price

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

Magento is missing the most simple feature of Bundle product. Magento's bundle product only supports base price and then adds each individual price to the final price. I don't want that.

I want to bundle up a few product and sell it with a single price. For example I have a  keyboard and mouse. Each they are selling for $25. But buy them both (in a bundle) I'll sell it for $40.

The customer doesn't get to pick what mouse or what keyboard or how many they want. These two product, in a bundle for $40. That's it. Buy it separately and its $25 for each.

Can it be done?

Comment: did you find a way to get this done, I am using magento 1.5 and want the same feature, thanks

Answer (score 6):

with 1.7 it works. you have to choose "fixed price" **before** you save the bundle! after that you can't switch back to dynamic price.

Comment: To quote our president: "Sad."

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around to get this done. Basically what you want to do is provide a 20% discount on the bundle product as compared to single simple product in your case $20 for each instead of $25 . What you can do is while creating the bundle product set the price as dynamic for the product with 20% discount (special price to be 80%) and then add bundle items with default quantity of one with checkbox input type. HTH.
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17061/s/simple-bundle-web-cooking-3892/

For simple bundles, directly configured on main product admin page!